# Excel XLOOKUP - find and return data containing text, but exclude if it includes other text

Tags: excel, find, xlookup

I have xlookup function searching range F1:F44 for the text in F2 and then returning the match:

```
XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND(F2,F1:F44)),F1:F44,,2)
```

However I need to exclude entries if they include text listed in array A1:A10.

I have tried switching over to something like this with the NOT, but always get an error:

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,(ISNUMBER(FIND(F2,F1:F44))*NOT(A1:A10),F1:F44))
```

I also tried

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND(F2,F1:F44)*NOT(FIND(A1,F1:F44))),F1:F44,"no match",2)
```

but in this case the result being returned contains the value in A1 that is supposed to be excluded with the "NOT".

Tried applying this suggestion:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,ISNUMBER(FIND(G2,DumpSample!F1:F44))*(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(TRANSPOSE(exclude!A1:A8),DumpSample!F1:F44)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(exclude!A1:A8)))=0),DumpSample!F1:F44,"no match",2)
```

and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
=XLOOKUP(1,ISNUMBER(FIND(F2,F1:F44))*(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(TRANSPOSE(A1:A10),F1:F44)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A10)))=0),F1:F44,"no match",2)
```

The MMULT()=0 will return an array of TRUE/FALSE.  TRUE if none of the values in A1:A10 are found in the cell, FALSE if found

Also where multiplying two Boolean we get either 1 or 0 so instead of TRUE we need to look for 1

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I am getting a too many arguments error with this suggestion

Comment: @asaysno sorry missed a `)` see edit

Comment: Problem now is that it is not returning any results based on what it should find from the F2 cell. Just says no match.

Comment: you will need to post some test data and expected output.  It is hard to debug without that.

Comment: one thing to remember is that `FIND` is case sensitive: `A<>a`  If you want case insensitive then use `SEARCH` instead of `FIND`

Comment: I posted some sample data, and updated to search instead of find, but still no match

Comment: still returning no match :(

Comment: F2 is in the lookup array, should that be something different.  I used E2 (see above) as it is working for me

Comment: Not sure why it is not working.  It works for me.  You may want to check the data.  Test a few cells that you think should match and do just the find and just the MMULT on that one cell to see if they return correctly.

Comment: You may have spaces or other non printable characters in the list in A1:A10.  That would throw it off.